# VSCode showing "cannot find module" TS error for .vue import while compiling doesn't

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Simply put, vscode is showing this error in a module:

> Cannot find module '@/components/SidebarToggleIcon'

**But no such error shows up during compilation.**

This is a VueJS project and `SidebarToggleIcon` is a `.vue` file with TypeScript in the `<script lang="ts">` section. This error was showing up before in VSCode and during compilation until I added the `@vue/eslint-config-typescript` package. Now is just shows up in VSCode.

**Sidebar.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
// [skip other imports]
import SidebarToggleIcon from '@/components/SidebarToggleIcon';

@Component
export default class LayoutSidebar extends Vue {

    get sidebarCollapsed(): boolean {
        return preferenceModule.sidebarCollapsed;
    }
}

</script>
```

**SidebarToggleIcon.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import PreferencesStore from '@/store/PreferencesStore';

const preferenceModule: PreferencesStore = getModule(PreferencesStore);

@Component
export default class SidebarToggleIcon extends Vue {

    get sidebarCollapsed(): boolean {
        return preferenceModule.sidebarCollapsed;
    }

    toggle(){
        preferenceModule.ToggleSidebar();
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Why is this? How do I solve this?

**Edit:** This is **not** an issue with the `@` alias, those resolve correctly (in the screenshot the line above the error uses it, and I use it else-wear in the project), this error still shows up when using relative paths. My TSConfig has the appropriate `"paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] }` item. If this was the issue compiling would also throw this error, which it does not, this is only present in VSCode.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting this error as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the Sidebar.vue file, try to add the ".vue" extension in import declaration , something like this:

```
import SidebarToggleIcon from '@/components/SidebarToggleIcon.vue';
```

Comment: This answer did the trick for me. Maybe it's related to shims-vue.d.ts where I have this:
`declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, neither with the config in the comment by @JavierPallarés

Answer (score 139):

For me, for a Vite & Vue 3 project in PhpStorm it was enough to create a shims file in the `src` directory. Most of my components use only script setup.

**src/shims-vue.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.vue';
```

Comment: This worked for me... but I have absolutely no idea why.  Can anyone explain what this does and why it means that the module (or corresponding type declarations) _can_ now be found?

Comment: Finally a quick'n easy solution to get rid of headache for setting up a bare minimum ts vue project.

Comment: Seconding the call for an explanation? For now I can only thank the magical sky fairies

Comment: it remove the warning but the component import definition is not navigable.. I fix it well with the downbk comment » https://stackoverflow.com/a/73710755/9485417

Comment: Worked for me also. but no idea how. can anyone please explain?

Comment: Nope, the warning is disappear but when you use 'F12' trying to jump to definition, it always jump to this file.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. no need of reloading VS code as well

Comment: I also would like an explanation, anyone?

Comment: If you're migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3, make sure to have only and only this line: declare module '*.vue';

I was having this:
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}

And didn't work unless I kept the line above.

Answer (score 112):

I've installed **TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)** VS Code extension and the problem was solved.

Remember to disable this VS Code built-in extension: **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**. You could read more [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode).

1. In your project workspace, bring up the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (for macOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
2. Type built and select "Extensions: Show Built-in Extensions".
   Type typescript in the extension search box (do not remove `@builtin` prefix).

[image: Search for "@builtin typescript" in VS Code Extension search box and select the extension "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features"]

3. Click the little gear icon of "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features", and select "Disable (Workspace)".
4. Reload the workspace. Takeover mode will be enabled when you open a Vue or TS file.
5. **(Optional)** If you have set custom path alias for webpack or vite (or other module bundler), remember to add path alias for typescript support

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* other configs */
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*" // set path `@/*` as alias of `src/*`
      ]
    },
    /* other configs */
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin

Comment: in fact, it seems that just having a tsconfig.json with just `{}` is enought in my case

Comment: Installing Volar fixed for me.

Comment: Why hasn't this been flagged as the correct answer.

Comment: I think this is the most appropriate answer, as it just disables the source of the error without having to change anything inside the codebase! Thank you. :)

Comment: Here are the instructions on the VueJS website https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode

Comment: This feels like the most correct answer.

Comment: This extension has been deprecated! See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin

Answer (score 57):

This is because TypeScript does not resolve webpack aliases automatically.

For TS to resolve aliases, they should be added in `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions.paths`:

```
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
   "paths": {
     "@/*": [
      "./*"
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reload your IDE after these changes

Comment: Webpack aliases are resolving correctly, see the line above that also has an `@`. This is not the problem. I can use direct paths and this still shows up.

Comment: Another option is that it does not resolve `*.vue` files correctly. Did you try to add an extension to the file to see if it works? Example. `@/components/SidebarToggleIcon.vue`

Comment: I have tried that as well. I even create a brand new vue typescript project with vuecli and the issue persists, but only in vscode.

Comment: SO, created a new clean project, and manually wrote in all my code, and I can now import with a `.vue` at the end of the filename for the import.

Comment: This didn't do the trick for me. I've yet to find out what's going to do the trick

Answer (score 19):

On my machine, VS Code extension [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) produces the error message for my `@/` imports in `<script lang="ts">` Vue components in my multi-project repository.

Seems Vetur looks in the VS Code workspace top-level folder for the `tsconfig.json`. My Vue app, with its `tsconfig.json`, is in a sub-folder.  Vetur does not pass along the correct settings when invoking the TypeScript compiler.

### Solution 1 (temporary hack)

Start VS Code from inside the Vue project's root folder.  (The same folder as the correct `tsconfig.json`.)

```
code .
```

Make sure the `tsconfig.json` contains the `compilerOptions.baseUrl` property in addition to the `compilerOptions.paths` property ([Vetur FAQ](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#vetur-cant-recognize-components-imported-using-webpacks-alias)).

This changes my VS Code settings and extension settings; as the project-level `.vscode` folder is no longer accessible.  (I use symbolic links to keep the workspace-level and Vue-level `.vscode` folders in sync.)

### Solution 2 (hack)

I have a single Vue project in my workspace, so I added a modified `tsconfig.json` file to my overall workspace folder, (the parent folder of my Vue application folder).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["myVue/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I needed the `"baseUrl"` property in addition to the `"paths"` property (again [Vetur FAQ](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#vetur-cant-recognize-components-imported-using-webpacks-alias)).

I reloaded VS Code for changes to take effect.

The `"exclude"` property may not be required, but I am paranoid of Vetur's invocation of the TypeScript compiler wasting time on the `node_modules` folder.

### Background

This may be related to the (currently) open Vetur issue [Multi root support #424](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/424).  (Summary: Vetur expects exactly one [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) in the VS Code workspace top-level folder.)

Answer (score 13):

A bit late but make sure to use workspace version of TS in VSCode so that it loads local TS plugins.
Refer to this comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/965#issuecomment-717248892

With VSCode, you can select your workspace TS Version:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

After adding the `.vue` extension on the import, I resolved this error by adding typescript shims for vue files.

I created a file in `typings/sfc.d.ts` containing this:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default Vue
}
```

References:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5298#issuecomment-453036640

Comment: I added this to my `src/` folder (using electron-webpack) and this fixed the problem. I just don't know WHY it fixed the problem...

Answer (score 5):

If you use `defineComponent` in your `*.vue` files in Vue3 you can add a shim for example in `typings/sfc.d.ts` as

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import {defineComponent} from 'vue';
    export default defineComponent;
}
```

Comment: This works very well as it is significantly more properly typed.

Comment: This is really good!

Answer (score 3):

If the Vetur extension is causing the error and you are using the tsconfig paths mapping, what worked for me was to create a vetur.config.js file at the top level folder specifying where to find the tsconfig.json file like below :

```
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    {
      root: "./yourprojectdirectory",
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig",
    },
  ],
};
```

It seems like Vetur will try to look for a tsconfig.json at your root directory  so if your project is inside a sub folder it won't be able to find it by itself.

https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/setup.html#advanced

Comment: Tried it but it doesnt recognize my tsconfig still.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using typescript and want to import component from external library in your vuejs project. This is how I solved my issue.

1. create `index.d.ts` file at `src/`
2. add this code -> `declare module 'myAwesomeLib'`
3. import component -> `import {SomeMethod} from 'myAwesomeLib'`

`*.d.ts` files are used to provide typescript type information about a module that's written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vue 3 you should add this into a type file like `vue.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type {DefineComponent} from 'vue'
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const component: DefineComponent<object, object, any>
  export default component
}
```

You can see it working here: [source](https://github.com/mutoe/vue3-realworld-example-app/blob/master/env.d.ts)

You must add generic types if you use VueTestUtils `mount` method.

Answer (score 1):

For Vue 3 (with typescript), consider this [fix](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/discussions/471). It works well with Vite also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but since I had these problems as well, even if I had the correct paths settings, vite.config.ts and tsconfig.json files, I figured out that I hat do use the newer Volar extension in vue 3 projects, rather than Vetur, wich I had installed from my older vue 2 projects.

- Uninstall or disable Vetur
- Install Vue Language Features (Volar)
- Install Typescript Vue Plugin (Volar)

--> See also https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#ide-support

Answer (score 0):

With VSCode, you can try install `TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)` and enable it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My typescript configs was right and I just could fix the message by uninstalling the [vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) from my VSCode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3, make sure to have in the file: **src/shims-vue.d.ts** only this line:

```
declare module '*.vue';
```

I was having this in Vue 2, and hadn't worked until I kept only the above line alone in the file:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

NOTE: If the mentioned file is not found in your `src`, simply create it :)